# Plot only when ma5 > ma10

Tags: plot, average, pine-script, moving-average

I just want to plot moving average 5 line only when it's above moving average 10. 
When it's under moving average 10, I don't want it to appear.

Can I adjust the transparency condition..? 
or is there another way to do it..?

Kindly please help. Still new in coding. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use series to change the `transp` argument in `plot`. You can however do it with `color` as follows:

```
plot(ma5,color=ma5>ma10?#2157f3:na)
```